# php wrong date format

Tags: php, mysql, date

i have this shopping cart in which it sends the orders to mysql database along with the date on when it was ordered: the code for the date is as follows:

```
<?
    include("includes/db.php");
    include("includes/functions.php");  

    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
            $price=get_price($pid);
            $date=date('Y/m/d');
            $user=$_SESSION['username'];
            $pname=get_product_name($pid);
            mysql_query("insert into `order` values ('','$pname','$q','$price','$date','$user')")

                or die(mysql_error());
```

it outputs the date as 2011/11,14. How do i get it to output it like the following: 14/11/2011??

Comment: That code is extremely prone to SQL injections...

Comment: im not focusing on the security aspects yet, im trying to get the queries to work 1st

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `$date = date...` line. I'm not going to give you the direct answer to your question, but have a look at [the documentation for `date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for starters. Also, you should really be using a `DATE` database field rather than a string to store that

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
date('Y/m/d');
```

for

```
date('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: if i change it to date('d/m/Y');
 it returns with : 0000-00-00

Comment: In that case, it's because your date field is of data type `DATE` and expects inserted data to be in the MySQL date format, which is YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: yes it was DATE as a data type of which i have now changed it to an integer....it now outputs the date, not the month or year. my php code looks like this now: $date=date('d/m/Y');

Comment: No, it wanted to be the DATE data type. By changing it to integer, it'll just store the first number, or try and do some strange maths, or something just plain undefined. You need to insert it as Y/m/d as that is what MySQL expects (and it's stored as YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss internally).